# Getting all text in logs between two timeframes

Tags: awk

Pls help me getting all text in logs between two timeframes.

example of log file

```
2014-10-23 00:24:37 .....some data
2014-10-23 00:25:37......some data
2014-10-23 00:26:37.......some data
Error code HO5006
2014-10-23 00:27:37...some data
```

I am using below `awk` command to get the text between `2014-10-23 00:25:37 & 2014-10-23 00:27:37`:

```
awk '$0>=from && $0<=to' from="$1" to="$2" logfile
```

Output which i am getting is

```
2014-10-23 00:26:37.......some data
2014-10-23 00:27:37...some data
```

But my expected output shld be

```
2014-10-23 00:26:37.......some data
Error code HO5006
2014-10-23 00:27:37...some data
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be a more elegant method in awk to do this, but this will do the trick:

```
awk 'BEGIN {capture="no"};{if ($0>=from) capture="yes"} {if (capture=="yes") print $0} {if ($0<=to) capture="no"};' from="$1" to="$2" logfile
```

This will set `capture` to "no" until it it finds a line that is greater than or equal to your `from`, it toggles `capture` to "yes", then prints lines until it the `to` variable is hit.

Comment: sorry for the late reply as i was out of town.. i have tried the soln provided by u and it worked ... thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `Error code HO5006` string is greater then the date string (almost any string starting with no number). So the lines not matching with date pattern should be printed if the from date is passed.

So my suggestion is:

```
awk --posix -v from="2014-10-23 00:26:37" -v to="2014-10-23 00:27:37" '
  {dt=$1" "$2}
  dt~/^[0-9]{4}-/{if(dt>=from)++s;if(dt>to)exit}
  s
' << EOT
2014-10-23 00:24:37 .....some data
2014-10-23 00:25:37 ......some data
2014-10-23 00:26:37 .......some data
Error code HO5006
2014-10-23 00:27:37 ...some data
2014-10-23 00:28:37 ...some data
2014-10-23 00:29:37 ...some data
EOT
```

(date pattern can be made more exact if really needed)

Output:

```
2014-10-23 00:26:37 .......some data
Error code HO5006
2014-10-23 00:27:37 ...some data
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: sorry for the late reply as i was out of town.. i have tried the soln provided by u and it worked ... thanks a lot :)

Comment: @jayshah: I'm happy if I could help! Please upvote the working solutions and accept the one you prefer!